# Proving lognormality of security in Black-Scholes market

Tags: black-scholes, derivation, risk-neutral

Can someone prove that for some security $S_t$ with drift $\mu$ and volatility $\sigma^2$ in a Black-Scholes market we have that $Y_t = (S(t))^{1/3} \sim \text{Lognormal}$, w.r.t. the *risk-neutral measure* $\mathbb{Q}$? Also, would the drift in this case just be $\mu$?

Comment: Define $\log Y = \log S^{1/3} = (1/3) \log S$. So since $\log S$ is normal, $\log Y$ is normal. Hence $Y=S^{1/3}$ is lognormal.

Answer (score 4):

To prove this and similar transformations of securities we resort to *Ito's Lemma*. Let us define $f(t, S) = (S)^{1/3}$ with derivatives $\frac{\delta f(t, S)}{\delta t} = 0, \frac{\delta f(t, S)}{\delta S} = \frac{1}{3} S^{-\frac{2}{3}}, \frac{\delta^2 f(t, S)}{\delta S^2} = -\frac{2}{9}S^{-\frac{5}{3}}$.

Simply filling in these values in Ito's formula yields

\begin{align}
dY(t) &= 0 \cdot dt \;+ \; \frac{1}{3}S(t)^{-\frac{2}{3}} \;+\;\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{9} S(t)^{-\frac{5}{3}}S^2(t)\sigma^2dt, \\
&=S^{\frac{1}{3}}\left( \frac{1}{3} S^{-1}(\delta Sdt\;+\;\sigma S dW(t)) - \frac{1}{9} \sigma^2 S^{-2} S^2 dt \right), \\
&= Y(t) \left( \left( \frac{1}{3} \delta \; + \; - \frac{1}{9} \sigma^2 \right) dt  + \frac{1}{3} \sigma dW(t) \right).
\end{align}

Which implies $Y(t) \sim \text{Lognormal}$ Here $\left(\frac{1}{3} \delta \; - \frac{1}{9} \sigma^2 \right)$ should be recognised as the risk-neutral drift and not simply $\mu$.

Comment: Thank you for the derivation. However could you maybe explain why it implies lognormality?

Comment: @Trader2B this is because it is the solution to an Ito SDE whose solutions are lognormal: $dSt = S_t( \mu dt + \sigma dW_t)$ where $\mu$, $\sigma$ are constant in time and non-random.